# Ignore query params when back browser button is pressed

Tags: angular

I have three tabs in my dashboard components. When any tab is clicked `url` is appended with `queryParam` with tab info (say `root/dashboard?tab=tab1`). 
If users clicked on multiple tabs and then presses back button, `queryParams` of previous tabs are shown, rightfully so.

However, I want to router to ignore all the `queryParams` and navigate to the previous route (say `root/profiles`).

How to do this in `Angular`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your router link you need to set the `replaceUrl` property to true. This will cause any links clicked to replace the current browser history location with the current link.

```
<a [routerLink]="['./']" replaceUrl="true" [queryParams]="{tab: 'tab1'}">Tab1</a>
<a [routerLink]="['./']" replaceUrl="true" [queryParams]="{tab: 'tab2'}">Tab2</a>
<a [routerLink]="['./']" replaceUrl="true" [queryParams]="{tab: 'tab3'}">Tab3</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

Check out the `skipLocationChange` property.

You can find documentation on it here: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

```
// Navigate silently to /view
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

This prevents the route from being added to the history so won't be in the history list used by the back button.